# Why is MCR 2016 MCR_CACHE_ROOT not working

Tags: matlab, hpc

I have a Matlab routine that I have compiled as a standalone executable for use on a computing cluster running PBSPro.  There can be thousands of instances running at a time.  With version 2012a I found that setting `MCR_CACHE_ROOT=${TMPDIR}` would increase execution speed by an order of magnitude.  Our cluster is removing support for some older applications so I am moving to Matlab 2016a with the same code, all that is changing is the compiler version.  When I compile the code and set the MCR cache as before I get an error that says

> Could not access the MATLAB Runtime component cache

The 2016 version of the code will then proceed to use system RAM until the node is out of memory and the job terminates with a memory failure.  If I don't specify an `MCR_CACHE_ROOT` the job runs fine, albeit slowly and then finishes.

The compile command is `mcc -v -o Program -m mFiles`, where `mFiles` is a cell array of files to compile.  The only difference is compiler, MCR and corresponding LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  I use the exact same compile script and source files.  The executables are side by side and the TMPDIR is fully read/write accessible.

What is causing the runtime component cache error?

Comment: I recently had a similar (path) issue with (R2016b) MCR deployment, not the same as what you're dealing with but maybe the details I uncovered could point you to a couple places to look. The source of my problem was this: the value of `ctfroot` was pointing to `MCR_CACHE_ROOT` instead of its root/install folder so packages/dependencies wouldn't load. I was able to get the correct value of `ctfroot` with a regex on %PATH% (MCR prepends `ctfroot` to the head of %PATH% when it launches). Knowing `ctfroot` fixed my relative path issues. Another avenue to consider is using the `-C` compiler flag.

Comment: Also, I know you mentioned that you have write permissions to `TMPDIR`, but I don't think that error message ("Could not access...") should come up if your executable actually has write permissions to that directory. Assuming that both you and your MCR app are telling the truth, I'd conclude that your MCR app isn't using the value of MCR_ROOT_CACHE that you think it is. Could something, somewhere (inside or external to your code) be overwriting it before/during your applications runs?

Comment: @peterfranciscook I printed the value of `ctfroot` at the start of execution.  The order of thing happening is, PBS job start, parallel engine starts, MCR starts -> "Could not access the MATLAB Runtime component cache." message, ctfroot is printed (all instances show the same root, TMPDIR), program runs, 1 instance of the program eventually takes all the RAM and the job terminates.

Comment: @peterfranciscook I also compiled with `-C` and extracted the ctf file and then assigned the MCR_CACHE_ROOT to be the extracted location.  This also run very slow and eventually terminated due to out of memory condition.  If I don't extract the ctf file, I get an error saying the MCR can't extract it.  Maybe there is something wrong with the MCR install.